# How to merge two JOINS together correctly?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Let's assume I have products and I save views and sales related to them.
Now I want to get the daily amount of views and sales for a specific product.
There might not be views or sales for a product on each day.

- **products**: product_id
- **views**: view_id, product_id, created
- **sales**: sale_id, product_id, created

```
SELECT products.product_id,
    COALESCE(views.sum,0) AS total_views,
    COALESCE(sales.sum,0) AS total_sales,
    views.day
FROM products
    LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT COUNT(*) AS sum, product_id, date(created) as day
            FROM views
            GROUP BY product_id, day
        ) AS views
        ON views.product_id = products.product_id
    LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT COUNT(*) AS sum, product_id, date(created) as day
            FROM sales
            GROUP BY product_id, day
        ) AS sales
        ON sales.product_id = products.product_id
WHERE products.product_id = 15041
GROUP BY views.day, sales.day
```

This return multiple rows for each day instead of one, I think the issue is that I can't figure out how to connect the JOINS together for each day correctly.

How to fix make this query work as intended? Any further optimisation recommended?

output (wrong):

```
product_id  total_views total_sales day
15041   23  19  2019-11-03
15041   23  37  2019-11-03
15041   57  19  2019-11-04
15041   57  37  2019-11-04
15041   70  19  2019-11-05
15041   70  37  2019-11-05
```

correct output would be:

```
product_id  total_views total_sales day
15041   23  0   2019-11-03
15041   57  19  2019-11-04
15041   70  37  2019-11-05
```

user "METAL" output:

```
product_id  total_views total_sales day
15041   1   0   2019-11-03
15041   1   1   2019-11-04
15041   1   1   2019-11-05
```

Comment: Second `LEFT JOIN` on `sales.v`?!

Comment: fixed. isn't the issue. I wrote this query just for stackoverflow to simplify the problem as the real query contains a lot more information

Comment: um I ran the SQL and it says:
Error 1: could not prepare statement (1 no such table: views)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using `UNION` instead of `join` on your `sales` and `views` tables

```
select p.product_id, 
    , coalesce(sum(case when t1.col = 'views' then ct else 0 end), 0) as total_views
    , coalesce(sum(case when t1.col = 'sales' then ct else 0 end), 0) as total_sales
    , t1.dt
from products p
left join
    (select count(1) as ct, product_id, date(created) dt, 'sales' as col 
        from sales group by date(created), product_id
    union 
    select count(1) as ct, product_id, date(created), 'views' 
        from views group by date(created), product_id) t1 on t1.product_id = p.product_id
group by p.product_id, t1.dt
```

Comment: does not return the correct result, updated the main question with the result of your query and the correct one to expect

Comment: try now, added join to day

Comment: works, but only if a day has views AND sales. if a day has sales but no views, it won't show the sales too

Comment: try the 2nd query

Comment: error: #1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Comment: try again, added comma in between cols

Comment: fixed the syntax, but still wrong result, will edit the result into the question now. actually the "0" in the result is correct, rest is just "1" and not correct

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your product has either views or sales, I would suggest:

```
select product_id, sum(views) as views, sum(sales) as sales
from ((select product_id, date(created) as day, count(*) as views, 0 as sales
       from views
       where product_id = 15041
       group by product_id, date(created)
      ) union all
      (select product_id, date(created) as day, 0 as views, count(*) as sales
       from sales
       where product_id = 15041
       group by product_id, date(created)
      )
     ) vs
group by product_id, day;
```

I doubt the `left join` to the `products` table is really necessary